# EntityFramework Enable-Migrations throws MissingMethodException

Tags: entity-framework-6

When I try to enable migrations in my database project (EF 6.1.0 stable) it throws a MissingMethodException:

```
Enable-Migrations -Verbose -Debug
Using StartUp project 'xxx.Data'.
Using NuGet project 'xxx.Data'.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo)'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo)'.
```

Anyone has a pointer for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with a downgrade to EF 5.0.0, enable-migrations, update packe to 6.1.0.